# Javascript Actions such as onmouseout and onclick not working for apex:inputtextarea with rich text enabled

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

While trying to call JavaScript functions on `<apex:inputtextarea>` with rich text enabled the call is not being made and alerts are not being displayed.

```
<apex:inputTextarea richText="true" id="oAssessAdditionalInformation" cols="80" required="false" value="{!textAreaOne}"label="Additional Information"    rendered="true" onclick="mouseClickNew()" />
```

Javascript code:

```
function SaveUpdateEmailRecord(){
console.log("Hello, I am in here !");
alert("Hello !!!");
}
```

I even tried `<apex:actionSupport event="onmouseout" onsubmit="SaveUpdateEmailRecord"/>` inside the `<apex:inputtextarea>` tags and also tried directly calling `<apex:actionfunction>` but with no luck.

The section is not being re-rendered, the whole page will refresh in the future.

Any pointers?

Comment: the standard stylesheets are disabled .... it is working fine for <apex:image> tags on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will little tricky to achieve.

The reason is that when we add `<apex:inputTextarea richText="true"` ... it add hidden text area and its own iframe that shows as a text editor.

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, j_id0:j_id4:oAssessAdditionalInformation" aria-describedby="cke_32" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

So when you add events to your text area its not get added to the text area which is displayed to user.

**Now how to achieve it:**

You can add custom JS to ck editor for example add below JS to your page and you will be able to see alert when you change anything in editor.

```
<script>

   for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {alert('test 1 2 3')});
    }

   </Script>
```

Same way you can capture other events.

Comment: Awesome this works!! Thankyou :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to know few points before trying this:

- Any html attribute used within apex component should have html- prefix like 
  `<apex:inputtextarea html-onclick="alert('hi')"/>`
- When you enable `RichText='true'` it is no more a normal HTML text area component. Salesforce internally uses [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) to render rich text boxes.
- It is little complicated in the way it renders and you cannot manipulate as normal HTML component (because it hides the html textarea, renders a new iframe with toolbar, communicates through iframe on event change)
- I am not sure whether there is a way to communicate from Apex Component to CKEditor currenly, but this will give generic idea on CKEditor https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772863/1343065

Comment: Thanks for the info .. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: It throws back the error cannot override attribute 'onclick' on component <apex:inputtextarea> when i add html-onclick="JS function"

Comment: I have linked the CKEditor solution to the stackoverflow answe. Did you had a chance to look into that ?

Comment: CKEditor is the worst. When using it to render rich text area it breaks the binding of the property with controller and does not sync back data. Any ideas ?

Comment: @chinmaybhusari I am not sure why this is coming up now

Comment: Facing the issue,it is making use of CKEditor useless otherwise. Your answer is perfect and do the point. The problem is with CKEditor usage with Salesforce

Comment: Sure I will try to play around and will get back to you with my findings :)

Comment: Here are the details of the issue. Let me know if you need more details :http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113099/ckeditor-when-used-to-rerender-text-area-to-rich-text-area-breaks-the-binding-wi.